# nuget version dependency resolution

Tags: dependencies, nuget, version

I've solution with projects structure like this:
App -> Infrastructure -> Application -> Domain

Also I've 3 nugets:

- Libs (1.0.0 and 1.0.1 versions)
- LibsRef (1.0.0 and 1.0.1 versions)
- LibsRefNew (1.0.0 and 1.0.1 versions)

LibsRef 1.0.1 and LibRefNew 1.0.1 refs nuget Libs.1.0.1 respectively.

Application has package ref to LibsRef.1.0.0 (and so Libs.1.0.0)
Domain has package ref to LibsRefNew.1.0.1 (and so Libs.1.0.1)

The [NuGet documentation for dependency resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution#dependency-resolution-rules) states a rule that will apply in this case:

> Nearest wins
>
> When the package graph for an application contains different versions
> of the same package, the package that's closest to the application in
> the graph is used and others are ignored. This allows an application
> to override any particular package version in the dependency graph.

And I see Graph:

```
Application -> Domain        -> LibsRefNew.1.0.1     ->    Libs.1.0.1
            -> LibsRef.1.0.0 -> Libs.1.0.0
```

And on Appication level I expect to see Libs.1.0.0 in resolution result but see Libs.1.0.1.
Why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it's the case, but the docs seem to be very misleading on this.

The 'nearest wins' rule only applies to direct references. Then 'cousin' dependencies don't have to be at exactly the same depth, they're just 2 references to the same package, neither of which are direct references.

None of the actual examples given in the docs contradict that, but it's definitely not the behaviour I'd expect reading the text.